# How to view files in container while building?

Tags: perl, docker

When I am building container I get next message:

```
Step 13/29 : RUN source $PERLBREW_ROOT/etc/bashrc && perlbrew install -j 8 --notest --switch $PERL_VERSION
 ---> Running in a4efbc14a7b5

Fetching perl 5.24.1 as /opt/perlbrew/dists/perl-5.24.1.tar.bz2
Download http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/S/SH/SHAY/perl-5.24.1.tar.bz2 to /opt/perlbrew/dists/perl-5.24.1.tar.bz2
Installing /opt/perlbrew/build/perl-5.24.1/perl-5.24.1 into /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1

This could take a while. You can run the following command on another shell to track the status:

  tail -f /opt/perlbrew/build.perl-5.24.1.log
```

But how to do `tail -f /opt/perlbrew/build.perl-5.24.1.log` if there is no container yet?

Comment: The `Running in a4efbc14a7b5` message includes a container ID if you _really_ want to `docker exec` into it, but I’d just wait.

Comment: @DavidMaze: Thank you. `docker exec` does not work. But you give me the idea. I found that I should use `docker run`

Comment: @EugenKonkov why not using `-v` with `perlbrew` ?

Comment: @MostafaHussein: Thanks. This resolve my question. Add answer I will accept it.

Comment: @EugenKonkov Done, don't forget to up-vote it too :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to access that intermediate container even if it was possible to do, It may not be helpful in other cases like when you have a CI and the build was failed then you need to check the reason. So I suggest switching to verbose mode in `perlbrew` using `-v` option which makes the output go to STDOUT instead of file.

```
-v| --verbose
Log output to STDOUT rather than a log file.
```

Comment: You too, do not forget ;-)